NVDA is skipping table cells when they contain input or select tags
When I activate the "+" button which adds a new row to the table, NVDA then no longer focuses on each cell individually and skips over them. If you let it read out one of the cells it does focus on, it instead reads them all at once.
JSfiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/0nc29jr6/1/


const rowStr = '<tr><td><input class="inp1" name="inp1"/></td><td><select class="sel1" name="sel1"></select></td><td><input class="inp2" name="inp2"/></td><td><select class="sel2" name="sel2"></select></td><td style="display:flex"><div><input value="+" type="button" class="inp3" name="inp3"/></div><div><input value="-" type="button" class="inp4" name="inp4"/></div></td></tr>'

$(document).ready(function() {
  addRow();
})

function addRow() {
  let row = $(rowStr);
 
  row.find(".sel1").append("<option>opt1</option><option>opt2</option>");
  row.find(".sel2").append("<option>opt3</option><option>opt4</option>");
  row.find(".inp3").on("click", addRow);
  row.find(".inp4").on("click", function() {
    remRow(row);
  })
  
  $("#tbody1").append(row);
}

function remRow(row) {
  row.css("display", "none");
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody1">

  </tbody>
</table>



This only seems to be an issue when the table specifically contains input elements like these. Using Tab seems to navigate properly but using the arrow keys does not.

Please click [edit], then [<>] and post a [mcve] here instead on an external website

So are you saying before you click that button, it would still read the initial table row, that already existed, correctly?

Thank you, have added a snippet.
@C3roe Yes that's correct - it seems to work at first but then adding a new row breaks the previous row.
